# How we can write for loop syntax in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, syntax

How we can differentiate for loop and for each loop in swift language ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/1186/loops/3839/for-in-loop#t=201611160959027760434

Comment: Try this:   
for var i = 0; i < 100; i += 1 {
    print("number \(i)")
}

Answer (score 2):

do like

```
for i in 0..<100 {
print("Number \(i)")
}
```

for more sample, you can get [here](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-alternatives-to-c-style-for-loops/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with some step, just use it (step is 2):

```
for i in stride(from: 0, to: 100, by: 2) {
    print(i)
}
```